# Filter dataframe based on aggregate count value of a column

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider a dataframe like the following:

```
Key | Value
A   | 1
A   | 2
B   | 2
C   | 3
```

I want to filter this dataframe based on the condition that only get rows with the key where the key occurs more than once.

So the expected output is

```
Key | Value
A   | 1
A   | 2
```

What's the most succinct way of doing this in R? Looking for a generalized solution where count the count can be > n

Answer (score 3):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Key) %>%
    filter(n()>1)
```

---

Or with `base R` using `table` and `subset`

```
subset(df1, Key %in% names(which(table(Key) > 1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
df <- data.table(read.table(text = "Key  Value
A   1
A   2
B   2
C   3", header = T))

df[, if(.N > 1) .SD, by = Key ]

   Key Value
1:   A     1
2:   A     2
```